# JavaScript possible to select all elements with classname that starts with (...)?

Tags: javascript

Use case:
Discord allows you block users but their messages will show up as "1 message blocked", I want to get rid of the messages all together.

Upon inspecting, discord uses a class "messageGroupBlockedBtn" + a random key like "-1PBBh-" to style the block messages.

My question is, is it possible to select all elements with class name that start with "messageGroupBlockedBtn" with javascript?

Comment: depends: are we talking `class="messageGroupBlockedBtn-1PBBh"` or are we talking `class="message dark-theme messageGroupBlockedBtn-1PBBh flex-bg-2"`? I.e. is it the _only_ class or is it just one of many classes?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans from what I see, only one class